# In its non-political form it is an intense expression of

Tags: meaning

I'm having a hard time understanding the sentence in bold.

> The origins of schizo-posting are uncertain. Clearly, the core of the
> genre’s tone and language were formed in the nihilistic corners of the
> chans, depicted in the era of Newgrounds animations and wiki page
> creepypastas. It's also easy to see how conspiracy theories and new
> age spiritual influences might be influencing the cultural stew that
> schizo-posting bubbled out of. According to knowyourmeme.com: “The
> phrase itself has been used on 4chan since at least 2016 when it was
> used as a general slang term and without its rage comic
> connotation.”**In its non-political form it is an intense expression of
> anger and nihilism that like many other things online became
> politicized and absorbed into an array of online identities and
> ideologies.**
>
> https://donotresearch.net/posts/millenarian-dreams-of-the-schizo-scene

Is it saying that

1. schizo-posting was non-political at first, but later became politicized and now there's only a political form of it,

OR

2. schizo-posting was non-political at first, but later became politicized and now there are both political and non-political forms of it?

Or it's not clear from the sentence?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sentence, as written, means schizo-posting is both political and non-political.

The key phrase is this: "*In its non-political form **it is** an intense expression of anger and nihilism...*". The present tense there means that it currently has a non-political form.

I can't speak to the writer's intent, and it's possible they weren't writing carefully and by "it is" really meant "it was". If that's the case, then it means it has only a political form now. My answer above is only about the meaning of that one sentence in the context of that one paragraph.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just looked around some schizo-posting meme accounts and as you explained, I found both types of memes. Much appreciated for your help.